# all possible combinations

Tags: ms-access, vba

i need to get a list of all possible combinations, not permutations.

to make sure i have the right name, 123 and 321 to me are the same thing and should only be listed once.

the code below does what i need but i can't convert it into MS Access vba.

i'm sorry, i know this is basic and it has been asked a million times but i can't find anything for MS Access that works for me.

```
 Sub test_print_nCr()
      print_nCr 7, 3, Range("A1")
    End Sub
```

2.

```
Public Function print_nCr(n As Integer, r As Integer, p As Range)

  c = 1
  internal_print_nCr n, r, p, 1, 1
End Function
```

3.

```
Public Function internal_print_nCr(n As Integer, r As Integer, ByVal p As Range, Optional i As Integer, Optional l As Integer) As Integer

  ' n is the number of items we are choosing from
  ' r is the number of items to choose
  ' p is the upper corner of the output range
  ' i is the minimum item we are allowed to pick
  ' l is how many levels we are in to the choosing
  ' c is the complete set we are working on

  If n < 1 Or r > n Or r < 0 Then Err.Raise 1
  If i < 1 Then i = 1
  If l < 1 Then l = 1
  If c < 1 Then c = 1
  If r = 0 Then
    p = 1
    Exit Function
  End If

  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer

  For x = i To n - r + 1
    If r = 1 Then
      If c > 1 Then
        For y = 0 To l - 2
          If p.Offset(c - 1, y) = "" Then p.Offset(c - 1, y) = p.Offset(c - 2, y)
        Next
      End If
      p.Offset(c - 1, l - 1) = x
      c = c + 1
    Else
      p.Offset(c - 1, l - 1) = x
      internal_print_nCr n, r - 1, p, x + 1, l + 1
    End If
  Next

End Function
```

thank you again

Comment: How can you not convert it?  This looks like VBA code - are you getting errors?  If so, what is the error text, and what line is throwing the error?  If there's no error, what is happening when you step through in the debugger?  In other words, what is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: The code from from an Excel workbook and uses cells to store data.  Not a great place to start from for an Access function.

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned, sorry, this is excel code and it copies the values in the workbook . I just need to be able to pass the values to a variable.

Comment: @grantnz. So you're saying this can't be converted? I'm going to try writing my own for access and will post back if I do. I can't find good combinations code for access anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it could be converted.  You could use a dictionary object to store the results (add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime)

Comment: just wondering why this topic is downvoted, whoever did it, can you explain? or where can i see the reason?

Comment: You are using MS Access but there are no tables mentioned in your question. If the data to be processed is in tables, you could use a CROSS JOIN to generate all possible combinations, and exclude the ones you don't want.

Comment: these are column headers, it's not data per se. based on these i will then create queries. crossjoining gives me results that i don't need. for example, if my set is 1234 - crossjoin will give me 1111 and i don't need it. how do i exclude them? the problem is that this needs to be dynamic and i coudn't think of a way to write code to dynamically exclude what i don't need

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best method to do this, but I would use a kind of binary representation. For instance, consider the word "boy" with the number of letters n=3. This word has three letters, so you can use something like this:

001 = y,
010 = o,
011 = oy,
100 = b,
101 = by,
110 = bo,
111 = boy.

The left side can be done with a loop from i=1 to power(2,n)-1 and transforming i  to a number in the binary basis. So, the only thing you have to do is to use the non null positions to build your combinations.

Probably there is something more interesting than this in Knuth.

Comment: this is out of my league, to write this piece, thats why i'm looking for ready made code that i can tweak. sorry, i can't even say if this is the right answer or not because i don't understand it.  thank you though

Answer (score 0):

i found this code here, and it gives me exactly what i need. you just have to create a table with numbers from 1-100. instructions at the link below

[enter link description here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1582748)

thank you everyone

```
Public Sub buildquery(strN As String, K As Integer)
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim intI As Integer
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim strFrom As String
    Dim strWhere As String

    Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QN")
    qd.sql = "SELECT N FROM tblN WHERE N IN (" & strN & ")"
    Set qd = Nothing
    strSelect = "SELECT QN.N "
    strFrom = "FROM QN "
    strWhere = "WHERE QN_1.N > QN.N "
    For intI = 1 To K - 1
        strSelect = strSelect & ", QN_" & intI & ".N AS N" & intI & " "
        strFrom = strFrom & ", QN AS QN_" & intI & " "
        If intI < K - 1 Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND QN_" & intI + 1 & ".N > QN_" & intI & ".N "
        End If
    Next
    strsql = strSelect & " INTO tblCombinations " & strFrom & strWhere
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

then test

```
Public Sub testbuildquery()
  buildquery "1,2,3,4,5,6,7", 3
End Sub
```